# Tag a git commit with a "tag" tag

Tags: git, tags, push

I have used the following command to tag my HEAD with a tag named "tag":

```
git tag -a tag -m "comment on my tag"
```

But when I

```
git push origin tag
```

I get an error:

> fatal: tag shorthand without < tag >

I don't get the same error for tag with different name. I suppose git treats this "tag" as its sub-command. Maybe it is not an often use case... but is it possible to push "tag" to a remote repo? I wouldn't like to push my other tags with

```
git push --tags
```

though!

Comment: If you look in the documentation of git push (ie. do `git push --help` and search for tag). You will see that `git push` has a specific keyword which you can use to explicitly specify that you can use for pushing tags. This keyword is simply `tag` (surprise!). So you could theoretically do `git push tag tag` where the first `tag` is a keyword and the second `tag` is the tag name. However, I agree with the answer below: naming a tag `tag` is inadvisable.

Comment: I have only tried "git push -tag tag" and "git push --tag tag".
Thank You! :)

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the git code (link below), we can see that during a **push** it is checking for keyword **tag**.

https://github.com/tnachen/git/blob/master/builtin/push.c

Short answer: Give the tag a meaningful name and do not use git keywords

```
static void set_refspecs(const char **refs, int nr)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        const char *ref = refs[i];
        if (!strcmp("tag", ref)) {
            char *tag;
            int len;
            if (nr <= ++i)
                die("tag shorthand without <tag>");
            len = strlen(refs[i]) + 11;
            if (deleterefs) {
                tag = xmalloc(len+1);
                strcpy(tag, ":refs/tags/");
            } else {
                tag = xmalloc(len);
                strcpy(tag, "refs/tags/");
            }
            strcat(tag, refs[i]);
            ref = tag;
        } else if (deleterefs && !strchr(ref, ':')) {
            char *delref;
            int len = strlen(ref)+1;
            delref = xmalloc(len+1);
            strcpy(delref, ":");
            strcat(delref, ref);
            ref = delref;
        } else if (deleterefs)
            die("--delete only accepts plain target ref names");
        add_refspec(ref);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

- Created a **new branch** off of the **tag** branch
- Switch to the **new branch**
- Pushed my code to remote repo

I deleted the **tag** branch afterwards.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks :) It seems a workaround, but it is funny, that it is possible this way and not with the usual approach! :)